# jquery file upload plugin: how to use callbacks?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to implement the blue imp jquery file upload plugin from: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/ as often stated already the documentation is very detailed, but for me as beginner to jquery not really understandable.

I think I have basically lets say almost zero experience with jquery, so if anyone could help me out or give me a him I would be very glad!

I have tried to set up the basic implementation as it is in the wiki and saved following as index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery File Upload Example</title>
</head>

<body>

<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script>

$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'server/php/',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        }
    });
});

</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

What I wanted to do is show the images that have been uploaded on the same page. I thought I need to do this in the callback when upload is finished. However, I have no idea where to put the code...

So, to find out where to put any code I simply tried to just get an alert-box and added this code | UPDATE: this works now:

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {alert("Message","Titel")});
```

I also tried to use simply (UPDATE: still does not work):

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload('disable');
```

as it is said in the wiki, but with no effect.

Am I using the code in the wrong place? The code itself should be OK I guess...

Thank in advance for any hint!

Answer (score 2):

If you bind to 'fileuploadcompleted' then you can trigger actions when the images are uploaded.

This can be done by chaining the bind onto the end of your fileupload.
e.g:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'server/php/',
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
            $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
        });
    }
}).bind('fileuploadcompleted', function (e, data) {alert("Message","Title")});
```

Or anywhere below your fileupload function call using:

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadcompleted', function (e, data) {alert("Message","Title")});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `fileuploadprogressall` callback function and compare inside the loaded and total data:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
  ...
}).bind('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
        if(data.loaded==data.total) {
             console.log("All photos have been done");
        }
});
```